# How to split AndroidManifest Android

Tags: android, gradle, split, android-manifest

I need to split my manifest for tablet and phone.

```
 productFlavors {
        phone {
            applicationId "packageName.app.phone"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IsPhone', 'true'
            versionName "1.0-phone"
        }
        tablet {
            applicationId "packageName.app.tablet"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IsPhone', 'false'
            versionName "1.0-tablet"
        }
    }
```

With gradle I split layout and src folders but I need to split AndroidManifest xml file too.Can anyone give some idea How can I do that.Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "packagename"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    phone {
        applicationId "packagename.app.phone"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IsPhone', 'true'
        versionName "1.0-phone"
    }
    tablet {
        applicationId "packagename.app.tablet"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IsPhone', 'false'
        versionName "1.0-tablet"
    }
}
}
```

Here is my full gradle.

**EDIT 2** 
So with many researching :) I found my answer.I wrote to  package name like ${applicationId}.It work well. But I really interest How to split manifest file.Can anyone share a link or something about this subject.Thanks.

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're using a default layout for your project, you'd have a folder structured as

```
app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
app/src/phone/AndroidManifest.xml
app/src/tablet/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Here `main/AndroidManifest.xml` is your default manifest, while the ones you put in the flavor directories are the ones you'd have special configurations in. These then get merged with your default manifest when building a flavor.

Comment: Yes I read an answer like your response and I research How can merge it.Can u give an example please @tynn

Comment: @OlcaySönmez you could give more information about your task. It'd be too broad to start putting ambigues examples without real application to your problem. But merging should be done automatically by `gradle`. Just try to define your differences in there.

Comment: I share my full gradle below "EDIT".My problem is with push.Parse see two package tablet and phone.When I use the phone debug or tablet debug I have to write the package name ,which I use it ,to android manifest.Therefore I must split my manifest.How can I do that.@tynn

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute manifest.srcFile:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        phone {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest_phone.xml'
            ...
        }
        tablet {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest_tablet.xml'
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used that and gradle give an error.Here is the error : "cannot resolve manifest.srcFile." @Biggemot

Comment: thats weird, maybe your gradle version is old?

Comment: is yot build.gradle looks like this?
android {
    productFlavors { ... }
    sourceSets { ... }
}

Comment: Below "EDIT" I share my gradle. Yes it's look like that. @Biggemot